# How do I specify the window height of the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, window, comint, inferior-buffer

Suppose I am editing a file in python-mode. If I start the Python interpreter using `M-x run-python` (or `C-c C-p`), the Python interpreter opens in a window (`*Python*`)  in the bottom half of the frame. Is there a way to automatically set the height of the Python interpreter window? I don't want the interpreter to take up half the height of the frame. I want it to take up less than half of the frame height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shackle](https://depp.brause.cc/shackle/),

for example

```lisp
(require 'shackle)
(setq shackle-rules '(("*Python*" :align bottom :size 0.25)))
```

Or if you use `use-package`

```lisp
(use-package shackle
:ensure t
:defer t
:commands shackle-mode
:config
(setq shackle-rules '(("*Python*" :align bottom :size 0.25))))
```

As you can see `:align` tells us where the buffer will appear and `:size` (between 0 and 1) lets you decide how much the frame it will take.